# Реализовать стек на паскале [закрыто]

Tags: pascal, стек, процедуры

Как реализовать стек на паскале с такими процедурами, как:

- внесение элемента в стек,
- извлечение(вместе с удалением) элемента из стека с определенной позицией (например: взять элемент с позицией 2, при этом весь стек сдвинется на одну позицию, так как при изъятии элемента, позиция освобождается)

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать стек на базе динамического массива, если он есть в вашей реализации Паскаля. Вам понадобится

* динамический массив
* номер индекса текущего элемента
* операция push увеличивает текущий индекс и записывает по нему данные, увеличивая массив, если нужно
* операция pop проверяет, если ли в стеке элементы, запоминает элемент по текущему индексу, уменьшает текущий индекс и возвращает этот элемент

Comment: Взятие элемента не с вершины стека _не должно_ быть реализовано в стеке (по самому определению, из стека можно брать только верхний элемент.)

Comment: @VladD что на Ваш взгяд лучше использовать в рамках моей задачи с [калькулятором?][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/263424/pascal-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E

Comment: @VladD и можно ли использовать именно стек для этой задачи? раз можно брать лишь первый элемент._. динамическая память- это интересно, но многие тонкости остаются темными

Comment: @Mayhem: Стек — как раз нужная структура данных для задачи с калькулятором. Вам всегда будет нужна именно вершина стека (последний, не первый элемент).

---
Если динамическая память доставляет проблемы, можно сделать простую реализацию стека ограниченного размера, типа [этой](http://pascal-programming.info/articles/stack.php) (первая ссылка в гугле).

Comment: Почему же не нужен? А если такой ввод: `1 2 3 * +`? Понадобится стек глубины 3.

Для вашего случая проверка на пустоту нужна. Если вам придёт текст `1 +`, вы попытаетесь взять из стека 2 операнда, но после взятия первого операнда стек будет пуст. Так что перед каждым взятием надо проверять, и если элемента нету, сообщать пользователю об ошибке.

Comment: @VladD но ведь опн имеет вид  число число <оператор> число <оператор> число <оператор>, я буду вписывать сначала два числа в стек, потом встречу оператор, достану два числа, очищу стек, применю к числам оператор, положу результат в стек и встрречу следующее(третье по счету) число, оложу в стек и так далее,

Comment: @Mayhem: не обязательно. В [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) первый же пример `7 2 3 * -`, требующий стека глубины 3.

Comment: @VladD, соласен, но тогда поменяется алгоритм решения._.я бы хотел сначала реализовать обычный ввод, тот, который я описал ранее._. в будущем можно будет уже добавить/переписать код, который будет менять алгоритм вычисления, в зависимости от вводимой строки._.
Ну так все же, в этом случае код будет принимать тот вид(см. ниже)?

Answer (score 1):

[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) Как раз нашел реализацию через динамический через
сделал нормальный стек:

```
Type
   PComp=^Comp;       {стек}
    Comp=record
            sD:real;
            pNext:PComp;
    end;
    var
            pTop:PComp;
    Procedure CreateStack(var pTop:PComp);   {процедура создания стека}
            begin
                    New(pTop);
                    pTop^.pNext:=nil
            end;
    Procedure AddComp(var pTopPComp;var sC:real);  {добавление элемента}
            var
                    pAux:PComp;
            begin
                    New(pAux);
                    pAux^.pNext:=pTop;
                    pTop:=pAux;
                    pTop^.sD:=sC
            end;
    Procedure GetComp(var pTop:PComp;var sC:real); {изъятие элемента}
            begin
                    sC:=pTop^.sD;
                    pTop:=pTop^.pNext
            end;
```

Comment: @Mayhem: алгоритм в том виде, как мы обсуждали в том вопросе, не меняется:

1. Пришло число — в стек его.
2. Пришла операция — достаём 2 числа из стека, применяем к ним операцию, результат кладём в стек.
3. В конце работы результат = единственное оставшееся в стеке число.

Впрочем, для старого варианта по идее глубины 2 хватит.

Comment: @VladD да, точно. согласен. никак не уловил сути что в стеке последний пришел-первый ушел. но все же лучше же ограничить стек? чтобы память не есть._.

Comment: @Mayhem: Ну, теоретически да, а практически стек размером в несчастный мегабайт даст вам глубину в 256К операндов, хватит с запасом.

Comment: @VladD то есть STACK_SIZE = 256;? но по сути, вводиться будет строчка, так как я описал ранее._. мне просто интересно._.

Comment: @Mayhem: Для статического размера покатит. Но вы потом обязательно сделайте динамический стек.

Comment: @VladD обязательно, спасибо за совет) еще вопрос, для чего нужны проверка на пустоту/полноту стека?

Comment: @VladD то есть ровекрка на пустоту, отчищает стек,проверка на полноту,просто выводит 1 или 0?

Comment: @Mayhem: Проверка на пустоту важна, иначе вам придётся всё время подсчитывать, сколько в стеке ещё элементов осталось. Проверка на полноту нужна только для стека статического размера.

---
Нет, что вы. Проверка на пустоту _говорит_ пустой ли стек сейчас. Просто возвращает `Boolean`.